# Keep alive UDP sockets in Background for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm using CFSocketRef to create udp socket to send and receive udp packets. The sockets are not receiving the packets in background. Please help me if there is any solution to keep the socket alive in background to receive socket all time. It would be great if system can handle the sockets in background for app to receive data continuously.